# how to store results from multiple regressions in a single dataframe in a neat way

Tags: r

I am going to run dozens of regressions of different Ys on the same X. I want to score the coefficients and standard errors of each regression to a single data frame. 
The dataframe is like

```
Y1, Y2, Y3, ... , Y50, X
1, 2, 3, ..., 50, 1
...
```

I can do it like for each Y

```
model1 <- lm (Y1~X, data = data)
summary1 <- summary(model1)
list1 <- list(coef=summary1$coefficients[2,1],se=summary1$coefficients[2,2]) 
# only coef of X is of interest
```

And then generate the dataframe I want by

```
df <- as.data.frame(list1,list2,...,list50)
```

I am a rookie, is there a more neat way to do this in R? I tried to write functions with the name of the variables as input, but it fails if I define it as `function(variable)` and use `variable` directly inside the function.
Thank you so much for your inspiration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `lapply` to loop over each `Y` variables.

```
cols <- grep('Y\\d+', names(data))

do.call(rbind, lapply(cols, function(x) {
  model <- lm(reformulate('X', x), data)
  summary <- summary(model)
  data.frame(coef = summary$coefficients[2,1],
               se = summary$coefficients[2,2])
})) -> df

df
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried your method. It returns with `Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 'wrong item in model formula' `. In the quotations is my own translation of the error message. Can you give a hint of where the problem can be?

Comment: I succeeded by using `model <- lm(data[,x]~data$X)`! Thank you again